# Avoid escaping all double-quotes in strings?

Tags: vb.net

In a string that has multiple double-quotes, is there an easier solution than escaping each and everyone of them?

For instance, here's an HTML string:

```
Dim test As Regex = New Regex("^<div class="blah">\r\n<div class="blah"></div>\r\n</div>\r\n<div class="blah">\r\n(.+?)\r\n<div> class="blah">\r\n", RegexOptions.Singleline)
```

Alternatively, to hold the string, can VB.Net be told to use another character than the double-quote, eg.

```
New Regex(@my string="" my other string=""@)
```

?

Thank you.

Comment: You do know VB's double quote escape is just another double quote? So your code is just `Dim test As Regex = New Regex("^<div class=""blah"">\r\n<div class=""blah""></div>\r\n</div>\r\n<div class=""blah"">\r\n(.+?)\r\n<div> class=""blah"">\r\n", RegexOptions.Singleline)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are certain that the @ symbol does not appear in your string...

```
Dim s As String = Replace("^<div class=@blah@>\r\n<div class=@blah@></div>\r\n</div>\r\n<div class=@blah@>\r\n(.+?)\r\n<div> class=@blah@>\r\n", "@", """")
Dim test As Regex = New Regex(s, RegexOptions.Singleline)
```

Comment: I'll leave it for others to comment on the irony of using Replace() in conjunction with a Regex :-)